# Remove not so same nodes in XML

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery

I have a XML like below and I want to get rid of second node as only class is different.
I can do this using XSLT or xqy or xpath.

```
<root>
   <name>
       <firstname>ABC</firstname>
       <class>12</class>
   </name>
   <name>
       <firstname>ABC</firstname>
       <class>11</class>
   </name>

   <name>
       <firstname>DEF</firstname>
       <class>9</class>
   </name>

   <name>
       <firstname>DEF</firstname>
       <class>10</class>
   </name>
</root>
```

Output expected is

```
<root>
   <name>
       <firstname>ABC</firstname>
       <class>12</class>
   </name>
   <name>
       <firstname>DEF</firstname>
       <class>9</class>
   </name>
</root>
```

Any pointers in this direction would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this using an XSLT transformation

Answer (score 3):

It is a grouping problem so with XSLT 2.0 use

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="name" group-by="firstname">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

with XSLT 1.0 use Muenchian grouping

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="name" use="firstname"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:for-each select="name[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', firstname)[1])]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

XQuery, given you can choose every second element:

```
<root>{
  /root/name[position() mod 2 = 1]
}</root>
```

Using XQuery update, modifying the original document:

```
delete nodes //name[position() mod 2 = 0]
```

If you need to compare if the name occured before (and thus only keep the first instance of a name), change the predicate to

```
<root>{
  /root/name[not(firstname = preceding-sibling::name/firstname)]
}</root>
```

respective the variant using XQuery Update

```
delete nodes /root/name[firstname = preceding-sibling::name/firstname]
```